# Toggle setLineDash()

Tags: javascript, html

I looked up how to draw dashed lines with the HTML5 canvas and discovered `setLineDash()`. It appears to work just fine in my browsers (Chrome, Firefox, and Safari) but I was not able to find the "standard" way to disable it

I have a function that gets called on an interval which draws some solid lines and then later dashed lines. My best guess was to do this:

```
context.beginPath();

// Toggle off the previous loop's dashed lines
if (context.setLineDash)
    context.setLineDash([]);

// Code to draw the solid lines

context.stroke();
context.closePath();

if (context.setLineDash)
    context.setLineDash([8, 8]);

context.beginPath();

// Code to draw the dashed lines

context.stroke();
context.closePath();
```

My main question is whether or not the below section is the appropriate way to toggle off the dashed lines:

```
if (context.setLineDash)
    context.setLineDash([]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Each CanvasDrawingStyles object has a dash list, which is either empty or consists of an even number of non-negative numbers. Initially, the [dash list](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dash-list) must be empty.

Dash list starts as an empty array `[]`, and thus you should set it to an empty array to reset the dash list to its initial state.

See also the `setLineDash` definition which also notes that the dash list [defaults to empty](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#2dcontext).

```
  void setLineDash(sequence<unrestricted double> segments); // default empty
```

Comment: To actually answer your question, your code snippet is correct. Keep the `if (context.setLineDash)` to ensure that the code still functions on unsupported browsers.