# Turn off dashed lines using setLineDash

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Struggling to make this work. Drawing lots of lines, some dashed, some not. After working a few times, it then goes random on me.  Below extracted from code:

```
var context;  // global

function drawArrow (dashed, c, x1, y1, x2, y2) {

context.setLineDash([]);
if (dashed === true) { context.setLineDash([3, 3]); }
```

using [] has been advised in other articles (over .length = 0) to turn off dashed lines.

See [Marching ant effect curves using setLineDash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474028/marching-ant-effect-curves-using-setlinedash)

or [Toggle setLineDash()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28823997/toggle-setlinedash)

Comment: Another way of controlling the stroke, is to use the strokeStyle member. See here for more: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_strokestyle.asp (I've not tried this approach in combination with setLineDash). Some more code would make it easier to identify potential sources of trouble. For instance, are you using `beginPath`, `moveTo/lineTo`, `closePath`? Missing the `closePath` from the end of the sequence can lead to unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using

```
ctx.setLineDash([]);

if(dashed == true) {
  ctx.setLineDash([5, 2]);
}
```